# "Too localized" is not the same as "very specific".

Tags: discussion, moderation, game-recommendations

Take this question for example, which has been closed: [Suggest a (steampunk) deepsea game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/suggest-a-steampunk-deepsea-game-closed).

The OP is asking for a game suggestion, of a very specific kind. And it has been closed as "too localized", and commented as "too limited in scope, there can't be an answer".

"Too localized" applies to questions which are too narrow in time, or in geographical situation. We don't want to have questions linked to only one country/region, or linked to a particular date, this is why such close reason exists. This is not such a situation.

There is no good reason to close this question. If it's too specific and there is really no answer... Then it will be forgotten the next day, no harm. If there is an answer, now or later, it will be given, and that's good. Nobody can claim to know any possible game.

We are complaining that people ask too wide "game rec" questions, and closing them. And when someone comes and ask a very specific one... it gets closed again. Let's be lighter on this kind of moderation.

Comment: Actually, "Too Localised" also involves "an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet." These are specific wishes which I doubt another person will share. With that said, I didn't vote for it as too localised.

Comment: @Arda you know, actually, after reading his question, I started wanting the same thing too, so I guess he's not alone ;)

Comment: What I meant was: I doubt someone's going to go: "Hmm, I really wish I knew a good underwater version of Arcanum: Of Steamworks and Magick Obscura (or Fallout) with floating vehicles, deepsea creatures, and non-Tolkienesque humanoids, let me search if it has been asked before."

Comment: Haha... I love the discussion my question generated at least. My wording made it sound more localised than it was in my head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree, no reason to close this question for me. I vote to reopen indeed.

I think a good Q&A site is very useful to answer also very specific questions and problems related to the topic (games in this case).

Otherwise any site or forum with a good amount of visitors can do it. This could be an added value for Gaming SE to distinguish from the mass.